# Angular5 - set color of div container dynamically

Tags: angular, angular5

With AngularJS this worked fine:

```
<div style="width:10px;height:10px;background-color:{{user.color}}"></div>
```

but with Angular5 it doesn't. How to do it with Angular5?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
<div style="width:10px;height:10px;" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': user.color}">...</div>
```

or

```
<div [style.background-color]="user.color">...</div>
```

[Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#ngstyle)

How to use ngStyle

> ```
> <some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">...</some-element>
>
> <some-element [ngStyle]="{'max-width.px': widthExp}">...</some-element>
>
> <some-element [ngStyle]="objExp">...</some-element>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle or ngClass for doing it Dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using inline css use class. You can use ngClass for that

```
[ngClass]="user.color"
```

pass the class name in property. So if you want to add more properties in css it will be easier then.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically change the color of a div with a Color Picker in Ionic 5:
watch this video for making the color Picker:
https://youtu.be/g4rQBQDUSJY
Then do the following below:

in HTML

```
<div id="picker"></div>
        <br/>
        <div>
          <ion-text>
            Color hex: {{colorCodeHEX}}
          </ion-text>
          <br/>
        </div>


<div [style.background-color]="colorCodeHEX">&nbsp;</div>
```

if you remove the `&nbsp;` it doesn't work

in TS

```
import iro from '@jaames/iro';  



colorCodeHEX:string="";


 ngOnInit() {
    let ref = this;
    var colorPicker = iro.ColorPicker ("#picker",
    {width:this.width1,
      layout: [
        {
        component: iro.ui.Wheel,
        options: {}
        },
    ]
    });

    colorPicker.on('color:change',function(color)
    {
     ref.colorCodeHEX = color.hexString; 
    });
  }
```